# CORS in WCF: web.config entries do not help but (equivalent?) Global.asax approach works! Why?

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, google-chrome, cors

I have a WCF Restful Service which is being consumed by JQuery (through chrome). I detected a Cross-Origin issue with POST method and was trying to resolve it. Things work perfectly when I added a Global.asax to the project and intercept ***OPTION*** requests and responds positively to it as in below code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, DELETE");

            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Things are working as expected with the above code.However this one below **(in the web.config)** which I thought would be doing the same is not working

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST, PUT, DELETE" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
```

Given below, the error details in chrome:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405
>   (Method Not Allowed)
>       Index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:61481/ServiceRest.svc/CreateUser. Invalid HTTP status
>   code 405
>       Index.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

**I am really curios on what I am doing wrong and trying to fill the gap in my understanding about it! Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance**

***Additional Info:***
Service definition is as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/CreateUser", Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        int CreateUser(UserData user);
```

JQuery is as follows

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: serviceUrl,
         data: JSON.stringify( {
             "Password" : "String content",
             "UserID" : "String content",
             "UserName" : "String content",
             "UserRole" : "String content"
         }),
         contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: "json",
         success: OnSuccess,
         error: OnError
         });
```

Comment: only difference i can imagine at this point is the  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") and the conditional approcah it would take. but not sure how does it matter! :(